# Entity Framework Core Configuration one to zero or one relationship with same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

In my .NET MVC project, I have my domain classes with one to one or zero relationship as:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PID { get; set; }
}
```

This is using EF 6.x and the Address entity uses PID (which is foreign key) as its identity column. This code is automatically configured in EF 6.x without any explicit configuration.

Now, I am porting this solution to .NET Core 2.1. Here, the EF Core doesn't work with the Data Annotations of EF 6.x. I cannot for example get the property `person.Address.City` It appears I need to configure it manually using FluentAPI.

So far I have tried three different configs, one after another to no avail:

```
//First config
       modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Address)
            .WithOne(a => a.Person);

//Second config
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .OwnsOne(p => p.Address);

//Third config
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .OwnsOne(p => p.Address)
            .OwnsOne(a=>a.Person);
```

This project has a lot of data and needs to be configured using the existing entity structure. Please help.

Comment: Did you checked http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx? For one to zero or one relation, you need reference navigation property at both sides and follow the naming convention.

Comment: I missed a property in the Person class, which I edited now. I checked the link but there, the dependent entity (which in this case is Address) has its own primary key defined. In my domain, the dependent entity only foreign key which is its primary key as well.

Comment: It would be simpler to add a field `public int AdressId { get; set; }` in Adress as a primary key and rename `PID` as `PersonId`. That way, you don't need neither fluent api nor data annotations

Comment: As explained in my question, adding a new identity field at this time is not an option, since the tables are populated.

Comment: I understand you want to use and preserve the data in your DB. Is it an option for you to create a link table, so you can link each address to each person through a seperate table?

Comment: The posted model works w/o explicit fluent configuration in EF Core as well (of course after fixing C# unsupported `Address.Address` property name). In fact most of the EF6 data annotations work with EF Core.

Answer (score 4):

Your first try was close, you just need to specify which field is the foreign key of the relationship using the *HasForeignKey* method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Address)
    .WithOne(a => a.Person)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.PID);
```

And for the sake of completeness:

```
public class Address
{
    [Column("Address")]
    public string Addr { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int PID { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need the *ForeignKey* attribute on the *PID* property any more as this relationship is configured fluently. Furthermore, your code produced a compiler error because classes cannot have members of the same name. Hence I added a *Column* attribute to workaround this problem.

Comment: what if we want to create one to zero or one without fluent api