# EF Core one to one to zero relationship not returning data in result

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm currently in the process of migrating an existing database design into a new application using EF Core 2.2.1 with code first migrations. Our current design has a primary table which then can have multiple sub tables with the same, shared primary key. I've looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259004/entity-framework-core-configuration-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-with-same-pr) and tried to replicate the answer there, but haven't had much luck in having the data show in the result.

The simplified schema looks a bit like the following:

```
public class Root
{
    public enum SubEntityType
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public SubEntityType Type { get; set; }


    public virtual TypeA A { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeB B { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeC C { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeD D { get; set; }

}

public class TypeA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Root Root { get; set; }

    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Root Root { get; set; }

    public Guid B { get; set; }
}

public class TypeC
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Root Root { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }
}

public class TypeD
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Root Root { get; set; }

    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

Then I've set up the relationships using fluent api as follows:

```
builder.Entity<Models.Root>()
    .HasOne( e => e.A )
    .WithOne( e => e.Root )
    .HasForeignKey<Models.TypeA>( e => e.Id );

builder.Entity<Models.Root>()
    .HasOne( e => e.B )
    .WithOne( e => e.Root )
    .HasForeignKey<Models.TypeB>( e => e.Id );

builder.Entity<Models.Root>()
    .HasOne( e => e.C )
    .WithOne( e => e.Root )
    .HasForeignKey<Models.TypeC>( e => e.Id );

builder.Entity<Models.Root>()
    .HasOne( e => e.D )
    .WithOne( e => e.Root )
    .HasForeignKey<Models.TypeD>( e => e.Id );
```

It seems to work great up until I try to add data. I create the root entry with some dummy data. In `root` table:

```
Id                                      Type
6f0f24cf-fbd7-4b4d-8059-0810daaf5460    1
```

In `TypeA` table:

```
Id                                      A
6f0f24cf-fbd7-4b4d-8059-0810daaf5460    12
```

Everything inserts fine and looks good. When I query this like so:

```
var result = ctx.Root.First();
```

I get the following result (apologies for formatting, tried to make it a bit nicer):

```
Name                Value
result              {Test.Models.Root}
    A               null
    B               null
    C               null
    D               null
    Id              {6f0f24cf-fbd7-4b4d-8059-0810daaf5460}
    Type            B
```

Shouldn't `A` be populated with the `Test.Models.TypeA` object with the `A` set to `12`? Is this an optimisation that EF does and I need to load `A` on demand or have I set up the relationship incorrectly? Alternatively, is my approach wrong here and I should be doing this differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Entity Framework Core, virtual navigation properties are not loaded automatically unless you [Configure Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) or use `Eager Loading` with `Include`.

So write your query as follows:

```
var result = ctx.Root.Include(r => r.TypeA).Include(r => r.TypeB)
                     .Include(r => r.TypeC).Include(r => r.TypeD).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now `Root` will have `TypeA`, `TypeB`, `TypeC` and `TypeD` associated with it.

Comment: Ah, knew I was missing something like that. Thanks!